# sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder$PNGException: crc corruption

Tags: java, exception, png, crc

I'm working in a big java project, with about 400 classes. Suddenly I got this error

```
sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder$PNGException: crc corruption
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.getChunk(PNGImageDecoder.java:699)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.getData(PNGImageDecoder.java:707)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:234)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:246)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
```

There has been a long time that I don't deal with images in this project and I can't see where the error is being caused, as it's not shown in the exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you have identified the image ? If so, you can check it with  [pngcheck](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html)

Comment: Thanks @leonBoy. I didn't know it was caused by an corrupted image.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. To fix this, I opened the project images with my image editor (GIMP) and exported them with a new name. So I imported the new images into the project and the problem was fixed. Hope it helps you too.